# Keil ARM compiler for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, microcontroller, stm32, keil

I am trying to go "all free" regarding the price for the software. So I decided to develop my code for STM32F0 in Eclipse and in Ubuntu.

I tried with different options regarding adding ARM toolchain to Eclipse.
The best I find is to download the special Eclipse version http://www.openstm32.org.

But It has some flaws regarding the compiler. Is there a way to add/import a **Keil compiler** to Eclipse IDE?

Because the same code worked on Keil very well.

Comment: Which flaws?
SystemWorkbench for STM32 (OpenSTM) uses GCC as compiler, which is pretty well tested every day...
The errors aren't related to compiler specific directives in the code?
in this case I recommend some search to find it's equivalencies in GCC

Comment: I described the flaws in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457168/openstm32-eclipse-ide-code-from-keil-not-workingpointer-variable-cannot-chang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar problem some time ago.
[topic on KEIL forum about Linux enviroment](http://www.keil.com/forum/20296/)

Anyway there are some older info here: [quite strict answer from KEIL](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1456.htm)

I would suggest you to try go deeper if you really want to go "all free".
Setup manually arm-gcc compiler, debugger (openOCD) and write own customized Makefile. Eclipse is an IDE which uses external compiler and debugger(so it's almost a text editor), the only thing it do is auto-generates Makefile- amd that may be a problem in some cases. It may be that not the compiler issues you a problems,but auto-generated Makefile from Eclipse, (wrong linker,lib flags or etc).

Anyway it is not the easy way, but you can find easily lots of pre-made Makefiles over github and with minimal customization you could load your project  freshly.

And yes, there are differences between KEIL compiler for ARM and ARM-GCC.
With standard libs, optimization and etc, those differences also may be a problem for you project.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.keil.com/forum/60502/) thread the keil eclipse plugin has been discontinued. You can try the methods discussed in that thread, but I suggest finding alternatives, like something similar to [this](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/).